# java.lang.NullPointerException when item selected from Jmenu and button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jlist

So this is a Jmenu that fetches data from database.The error is that when the **View Definition** button is pressed,then the corresponding event doesn't get triggered. Ideally when the user selects an item from Jmenu and presses this button then again the database is connected to fetch the corresponding value from the database based on the item selected from Jmenu. However the statement

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");
```

never seem to execute and throws an error

```
datajava.lang.NullPointerException
```

What is the error that is causing this and how to fix this ? This is my code:-

```
public class ListModelExample extends JPanel {

  JList list;

  DefaultListModel model;

  public ListModelExample() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(model);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("View Definition");

     Connection con;
      ResultSet rs;
      Statement st = null;

    try {  

        File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
        String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       st = con.createStatement();


       } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed to Connect to Database","Error Connection", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
System.exit(0);  
   }  


 try {  
     model.clear();  
     rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics");  
     while (rs.next())
     {  

         model.addElement(rs.getString("Metric_Name"));  
     }  

    } 
 catch (Exception e)
    {  
     System.out.println("Error in fetching data");  
    }
   addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      Statement st;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

          String def = ""; 


          try {  

                 model.clear();  
                 st = null;
                 System.out.println("came here");
                 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");  
                 System.out.println("came here too");
                 while (rs.next())
                 {  

                     def = rs.getString("Metric_Name");

                     System.out.println(def);
                   //  model.addElement(rs.getString("Metric_Name"));  
                 }  

                } 
             catch (Exception e1)
                {  
                 System.out.println("Error in fetching data"+e1);  
                }
          System.out.println(def);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, def, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      /*  model.addElement("Element " + counter);
        counter++;*/
      }
    });

    add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(addButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("List of Metrics used");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new ListModelExample());
    frame.setSize(260, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

This this the error I get when I do e1.printStackTrace();
and line 94 in my code is

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ListModelExample$1.actionPerformed(ListModelExample.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)Error in fetching datajava.lang.NullPointerException


    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace or logs? also to provide more debugging details, use the e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Sir I've now updated my problem !

Comment: OK that's good. And now.. which is line 94?  If you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) to go with it, we can easily tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                 st = null;
                 System.out.println("came here");
                 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");
```

I noticed this part of your code above, it will really be causing a null pointer.

To fix this, put the declaration of this 'st' as a field or member variable of your main class (ListModelExample). And remove the st=null and 'Statement = st' member variable declaration inside your listener.

```
    File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
    String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   st = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: :so how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code:

```
st = null;
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(...);
```

You can't call any method on a null reference without getting a NullPointerException. You `st` variable needs to be initialized to a non-null Statement.

Answer (score 2):

You first set the `st` to null and then try to executeQuery

```
             st = null;
             System.out.println("came here");
             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");
```

Instead call con.prepareStatement(String sql) to get the `st`

Comment: :removing st=null alsso doesn't solve the problem sir ! how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your **public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)** method

```
st = con.createStatement();
```

full code:

```
public class ListModelExample extends JPanel {

      JList list;

      DefaultListModel model;
      Connection con;
      public ListModelExample() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(model);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("View Definition");


          ResultSet rs;
          Statement st = null;

        try {  

            File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
            String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           st = con.createStatement();


           } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed to Connect to Database","Error Connection", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
    System.exit(0);  
       }  


     try {  
         model.clear();  
         rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics");  
         while (rs.next())
         {  

             model.addElement(rs.getString("Metric_Name"));  
         }  

        } 
     catch (Exception e)
        {  
         System.out.println("Error in fetching data");  
        }
       addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          Statement st;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              String def = ""; 
              st = null;

              try {  

                     model.clear();  

                     st = con.createStatement();
                     System.out.println("came here");
                     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select Metric_Name from Metrics where Metrics.Metric_Name='NAA'");  
                     System.out.println("came here too");
                     while (rs.next())
                     {  

                         def = rs.getString("Metric_Name");

                         System.out.println(def);
                       //  model.addElement(rs.getString("Metric_Name"));  
                     }  

                    } 
                 catch (Exception e1)
                    {  
                     System.out.println("Error in fetching data"+e1);  
                    }
              System.out.println(def);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, def, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          /*  model.addElement("Element " + counter);
            counter++;*/
          }
        });

        add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(addButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

      }

      public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("List of Metrics used");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new ListModelExample());
        frame.setSize(260, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input too ! Could you please help in fixing one thing. I want to increase the height of the jmenu but somehow struggling to do so. My attempt to do so either increases the size of button or makes them disappear and there is no effect in the size of jmenu. How to fix this ?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get your problem. Please share sample code and create a different thread. Thank you.

Comment: the code is same as above. I just want that the height of jmenu increases